# enhance flag dialog box with more descriptive choices

Tags: feature-request, flags

When clicking *flag* on a question, a dialog box pops up with 4 radio buttons:

1. it needs ♦ moderator attention
2. it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate
3. it is spam
4. it is not welcome in our community

Only for option #1 there is a room for more explanation and as it turns out now, this is because by default the top option is selected. I always turned down option 2 through 4 because I thought they just didn't fit my reason for flagging and was unable to elaborate on why I was flagging. Only when selecting one of the other options (and especially #2) a dialog pops up which gives a lot more options (exact duplicate, not constructive, not a real question, too localized).

<s>Until recently I never realized that flags are split up into</s>

```
A) a ♦ moderator queue
B) a 10k+ rep queue
```

and because I wasn't aware of the difference *and*

I just wasn't sure about the lower three flag options, I always picked the top one where I could explain my worries in a few words.

To turn this near blog post in a question:

<s>* Can the difference between flagging to the '♦ moderator' and the '10k+ rep' queues be made more clear, so people don't unnecessarily bother '♦ moderators' *and* get quicker response to flagging to 10k+ rep users?</s>

In my opinion it would help if:

- by default none of the four radio buttons is selected, so the text box does not appear by default *and*
- a clear indication that more text is to follow once a radio button is clicked. Eg. by ending the text in "I think because ..." *or* by popping up a little box when hovering over it which elaborates on the options that will follow.

Can the flag dialog box be improved in such a way that new users can find their way more easily in choosing the right flag?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the 10k+ queue. We don't really handle flags, we just evaluate the flags we're shown and cast our own flags agreeing or disagreeing. Ultimately, the moderators handle them. (Except if e.g. enough people raise a spam flag before a moderator looks at the post.)

Comment: @DanielFischer - fair enough, I guess I misunderstood that part. That doesn't change my opinion about the dialog box can be improved in such a way that it makes it easier for users to pick the other choices but the top one.

Comment: That is of course independent of how the flag queues work.

Comment: I've had [the same problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165552/139162) with the flag dialog where I didn't realize that there were more options, flagged as other and wrote "Too localized, blablabla".